# Webcam stopped working after installing V4L-DVB Device Drivers

Tags: fedora, drivers, kernel-modules, camera

On Fedora 24 my built-in laptop webcam was working fine. But, for some reason, I've installed [V4L-DVB driver](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers). After rebooting my webcam stopped working, every webcam software tells me that no video device is found. Also there is no such thing as /dev/video0 in my filesystem. Can I fix this somehow? Maybe by uninstalling the driver, but I don't know how to remove it.

Booting into older kernel fixes the problem. Still I'd like to use the newest kernel version.

Comment: What kernel version works and what version doesn't? What exact webcam model do you have?

Comment: @Gilles it's a laptop's built-in webcam. It's not a problem with the kernel version. I simply installed the driver on 4.6.5-300 kernel and I guess I've overriden some files. The webcam works on kernel 4.6.4-301, because I haven't damaged that one.

Answer (score 1):

Boot with the old kernel version (4.6.4-301), then uninstall the package for kernel version 4.6.5-300 using your favorite package management tool.

Then ensure `/lib/modules/4.6.5-300` directory is completely gone (delete it manually if it's still there) and reinstall the newest kernel package. Then reboot again with the latest kernel.